# what is the best folder structure for parent and child components in angular

Tags: angular, module, model, parent-child, directory-structure

[image: parent and child components implementing structure]

Above picture is the implementing structure of parent and child components. 
I have an idea about angular basic folder structure, but I need some small clarifications. Below I have mentioned the structure that I have created currently

```
app
├── features
│   └── feature 1
│        ├── parent A
│        │     └── parentA.component.ts 
│        │
│        ├── parent B
│        │     └── parentB.component.ts
│        │
│        ├── shared
│        │     └── models(models that are using inside the Feature 1)
│        └── core
│              └── service Q
│
├── shared
│    ├── components
│    │     └── header
|    └── models(models that are use inside every feature)
└── core
     └── service R
```

My questions are:

---

1. Where do I create child components?
2. I'm using shared and core folders inside features as well, Is that correct?

Comment: "I'm using shared and core folders inside features as well", the very reason for placing components inside shared is to use them where ever you want, so it's okay to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1. You can create your child components below parent A folder and should add routing module for parent A folder.
Answer 2. Yes, if your shared and core module's usage is limited to feature module then you can absolutely go with your current flow.

app
├── features
│   └── feature 1
│        ├── parent A
│        │     └── child Aa
│        │          └── childAa.component.ts 
│        │     └── child Ab
│        │          └── childAb.component.ts 
│        │     └── parent A-routing-module.ts 
│        │
│        ├── parent B
│        │     └── parentB.component.ts
│        │
│        ├── shared
│        │     └── models(models that are using inside the Feature 1)
│        └── core
│              └── service Q
│
├── shared
│    ├── components
│    │     └── header
|    └── models(models that are used inside every feature)
└── core
     └── service R

Comment: "child X" is common for both parents and also "child Z" is a child of  "child Y". I have uploaded a picture of implementing structure. Please refer it and let me know do you have any idea about it.

Comment: in that scenario, you should create child X component in Feature 1 itself and use feature1-routing for both Parents.